# AngularJS 2.1.0 official scaffold & style?

Tags: angularjs, angular, directory-structure, angular-cli

Google knows best… but they're inconsistent!

The [official `ng` CLI](https://cli.angular.io) generates a scaffold one way, whereas the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) chooses a different way.

I'm not talking just directory layout, `typings.json` vs types in `package.json` choices are also particularly worrisome.

What style am I meant to work with?

Comment: Hmm, just found this https://angular.io/styleguide

Comment: UPDATE: As of [4 days ago in the official tutorial](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/commit/e33ed9a3adb1e1b9639bd16bcf27e621aba6e092), `typings.json` was removed and replaced with `@types` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## QuickStart

> This is not the perfect arrangement for your application. It is not designed for production. It exists primarily to get you started quickly with learning and prototyping in Angular

- [angular/quickstart/README.md](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/341eb5446625553eb8cc60b65ec4e21ef86f2993/README.md)

## angular-cli

> The Angular2 CLI makes it easy to create an application that already works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices!

- https://cli.angular.io

---

See also: https://angular.io/styleguide

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2's tutorial basically just shows the quickest and easiest way to get up and running with the framework. It omits mentioning things that could scare away a potential newcomer to the ecosystem, it is meant to be simple.

`angular-cli` on the other hand actively incorporates best practices, latest technologies like Webpack 2 Beta and tries to give developers a piece of software to quickly scaffold and develop scalable production apps without worrying about build-tools and configuration.